# Sentence Builder app in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to complete an assignment for a new C# class using VS doing a windows form application (all new to me, code and all).  We were assigned to creating a sentence builder with various words that were buttons; and then when the app runs, the user could click the buttons to build a sentence; which is then shown in the Label control.

Well, I have the form built, and from other info I found on this site for a similar question; have made it to this point.  BUT my problem is - my instructor said we should be concatenating the results within the Label output, but FIRST I dont' know how to do that with someone just randomly clicking letters or words**(with what we have learned so far).

I got it to run with the following code(without concatenationin Label); except the "spaceButton" event puts IN the text of "(Space)" because that is it's text... I changed it to " " in the code and If I click on it running, it will now put in spaces but changes the text in the running app to a blank button.  I don't know how to fix that.

I have had this instructor before and while I might be able to work around the concatenation in the "sentenceOutputLabel"  - I might very well get a zero because I didn't concatenate in the output label.

Laura

Here is all the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sentence_Builder
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void upperCaseAButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string output;
        output = upperCaseAButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void lowerCaseAButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = lowerCaseAButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void upperCaseAnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = upperCaseAnButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void lowerCaseAnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = lowerCaseAnButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void upperCaseTheButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = upperCaseTheButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void lowerCaseTheButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = lowerCaseTheButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void manWordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = manWordButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void womanWordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = womanWordButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void dogWordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = dogWordButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void catWordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = catWordButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void carWordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = carWordButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void bicycleWordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = bicycleWordButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void beautifulWordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = beautifulWordButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void bigWordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = bigWordButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void smallWordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = smallWordButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void strangeWordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = strangeWordButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void lookedAtWordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = lookedAtWordButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void rodeWordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = rodeWordButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void spokeToWordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = spokeToWordButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void laughedAtWordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = laughedAtWordButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void droveWordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = droveWordButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void spaceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = spaceButton.Text = " ";
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void periodButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = periodButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }

    private void exclamButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        output = exclamButton.Text;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
    }
     / I DON'T EVEN KNOW WHAT I NEED THIS below FOR NOW
    private void sentenceOutputLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //string output;
       // sentenceOutputLabel.Text = sentenceOutputLabel.Text;
    }

    private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text = "";
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
  }     
}`
```

Comment: [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please ... don't need your whole HW

Comment: Thank you John, I wasn't aware about the minimal, complete, verifiable issue.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the assignment description correctly, this is what I would do:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StringBuilder
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;
            if (button != null)
            {
                if (button.Text == "Space")
                    lblOutput.Text += " ";
                else
                    lblOutput.Text += button.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, every single button can be assigned to the `btnInput_Click` event handler, and `lblOutput` is just the output.

Comment: That is simply cool and I had no clue it could be done.  I think I will start a new project and then see what happens!  :)

Comment: Yeah it's really easy! If you have any more questions about the code just let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution might just be so simple, it didn't occur to you it was allowed:

```
private void spaceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string output;
    output = " "; // don't necessarily have to use the Text property of the button ...
    sentenceOutputLabel.Text += output;
}
```

Comment: I just read your question again, and noticed your concern over the instructor counting off for not using the `Text` property of the button pushed. I don't think this should be a concern, because - where it makes sense to do so - you _are_ using the button text and - where it does not make sense to do so (i.e., `(Space)` being shown for " ") - you are not.

Comment: In the picture of what the output was supposed to look like, the button called "space" button looked like this:  (Space) and that was what was written on the button (text)  trying to get it to just give a space is what seems to be the problem.. John C - changing the code as above worked!  Thanks so much!  Now I just have to see if my code under the sentenceOutputLabel method needs editing.

Comment: In that case, I would [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) one of these answers before moving on to the rest of my homework - it's more-or-less how people on this site get paid. I would accept Brad Christie's answer, personally, as he gave a better way to do the same thing (the `Tag` property), and he did so without selling out and just giving you the answer as all others did (including me!)

Comment: I think I just deleted my own comment.  Thank you Jonn, C; that above solved the " " and text problem.  I was playing around with the sentenceOutputLabel method and since I did the += in the individual methods.. I can leave it blank and it runs fine.  My concern was if I had to concatenate in the sentenceOutputLabel method, and didn't know what a user would click to add.. .how was I supposed to do it.. John I didn't know that you all were paid by acceptance of any answers.  I read on to yours after his because I didn't understand the tag property because we haven't used it yet.  I am sorry.

Comment: I think I am going to go play around with the tag property now.

Comment: @Lorelei7: Have a look at the code posted in the comment to my question. I didn't want to give it away, but is an implementation using `.Tag`. Best of luck with your assignment! -- & @John, You're too kind, but I was just trying to help in a more general way. Still posted code, but did so as a GitHub branch. ;p

Comment: Just a quick fyi, at this stage in my game, nothing given to me was a sell out, as for most all of it, it will require more studying on my own to even understand it.  If I don't understand how the code works in conjunction with the form, etc.. I won't use it in my assignment because I could be called on in class to show everyone how my results work.  Thank you all!  Learning tool for me.

Comment: @BradChristie - no worries, and the Tag property was still the key, IMO. Lorelei7 - OMG, there's no $$ here ... I meant reputation gain is the goal of those answering ... knew I should've taken care when I typed that.

Comment: @Lorelei7 RE: selling out, maybe I typed too quick there, did not mean any sell out on _your_ part ... when answering questions that are clearly HW (whether stated out-right as in your question or O/W), I was referring to those of us providing answers striving to not just throw out the easiest, quickest, answer, but to try to provide just enough for the OP to find the answer on their own ... that is how we truly learn something.

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you the solution, but maybe I can provide a bit more guidance and assist in the learning process.

First off, the value you're concatenating doesn't *have* to come from the button itself. The way you have it setup, each button has a designated event (`*_CLick(object,EventArgs)`). If you already know what button's being click, using that button's `.Text` isn't really necessary. So, feel free to use the desired result within this method and not stick to the button's `.Text`.

Also, based on what you've described, you're fulfilling the concatenation part (you seem reluctant to believe this). Every time you append (`+=`) the clicked item's text to the label's current value you're concatenating (just C# is doing to work for you).

To take it a step further though, each control has a [`Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. This allows you to specify metadata and bind it to *that specific control*. You may want to consider specifying the desired output (with regards to what's added to the final label) as the button's tag, then appending that value (over the button's Text). You could also re-use a single `*_Click(object,EventArgs)` method and just concatenate `((Button)sender).Tag`.

Comment: The `Tag` property seems the right approach ... this just very well might be what the instructor is looking for, in terms of not giving credit for not concatenating using a property of `Button`.

Comment: If you need more insight: https://github.com/bchristie/StackOverflow-Examples/tree/question-28141853

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can use a common click event, and how you can use the Tag property to store the value to be added to the label (which may be different than the value displayed on the Button text).

I'm dynamically adding the buttons, which you wouldn't have to do, but this way you can copy/past the code into a new project and run it. Hopefully it is instructive, but not something you would turn in as your own work.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Label sentenceOutputLabel = new Label();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int padding = 10;

        // Add a label to the form
        sentenceOutputLabel.Width = ClientSize.Width - (padding * 2);
        sentenceOutputLabel.Top = padding;
        sentenceOutputLabel.Left = padding;
        sentenceOutputLabel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        Controls.Add(sentenceOutputLabel);

        // List of words that, for each one, we'll add a button to the form
        // Note that some words have two parts: the first part is the button 
        // text, followed by a colon, then followed by the tag text. We split
        // these out later, when assigning button properties
        var words = new List<string>
        {
            "A", "a", "An", "an", "The", "the", "man", "woman", "dog", "cat", 
            "car", "bicycle", "beautiful", "big", "small", "strange", "looked",
            "rode", "spoke", "laughed at", "drove", "[space]: ", "[period]:.",
            "[exclamation]:!"
        };

        // Get the width of the longest word so we size the buttons accordingly
        int width;
        using (Graphics cg = CreateGraphics())
        {
            width = Convert.ToInt32(cg.MeasureString(words.Aggregate("", (max, cur) =>
                (cg.MeasureString(max, new Button().Font).Width) >
                (cg.MeasureString(cur, new Button().Font).Width)
                    ? max
                    : cur), new Button().Font).Width);
        }

        // Add the buttons to the form, spacing them evenly
        int left = padding;
        int top = sentenceOutputLabel.Bottom + padding;
        int bottomOfLastButton = 0;

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            // For some words, we have a colon-separated symbol that we 
            // will use instead of the word (like 'space', for example)
            // So we store the symbol in the 'Tag' property and the word
            // in the text property.
            var wordParts = word.Split(':');
            var text = wordParts[0];
            var tag = wordParts.Length > 1 ? wordParts[1] : text;

            var button = new Button
            {
                Text = text,
                Tag = tag,
                Left = left,
                Top = top,
                Width = width,
                Visible = true
            };

            // HERE WE ADD A COMMON CLICK EVENT
            button.Click += wordButton_Click;

            // Add the button to the form
            Controls.Add(button);

            // Reset left and top if we're going past the width of the form
            left += (width + padding);
            if (left + width + padding > ClientSize.Width)
            {
                left = padding;
                top += button.Height + padding;
            }

            bottomOfLastButton = button.Bottom;
        }

        // Add a clear and exit button
        var exitButton = new Button
        {
            Top = bottomOfLastButton + (padding * 2),
            Text = "Exit",
            Left = ClientSize.Width - padding - width,
            Width = width
        };
        exitButton.Click += exitButton_Click;

        var clearButton = new Button
        {
            Top = bottomOfLastButton + (padding * 2),
            Text = "Clear",
            Left = exitButton.Left - padding - width,
            Width = width
        };
        clearButton.Click += clearButton_Click;

        Controls.Add(exitButton);
        Controls.Add(clearButton);
    }

    void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sentenceOutputLabel.Text = "";
    }

    void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    void wordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var wordButton = sender as Button;

        if (wordButton != null)
        {
            sentenceOutputLabel.Text += wordButton.Tag;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no worries of my copying code.. for one; I consider it dishonest and for two, I have no idea what half of yours means.  I am really new at this, like 2 weeks into class.  Thanks for sharing your example.